# sendRawTransaction results in queued TXs

Tags: ethereum

I attempted to send raw TXs via `eth.sendRawTransaction` API but get stuck. I'm using EthereumJS to generate and sign TXs, and indeed, I can submit TXs through `eth.sendRawTransactin`, but the TXs always result in queued (non-processable, per geth doc).

I called `eth.sendRawTransactin` from a geth console, and it returns a hash as usual. I can get transaction details by that hash:

```
> eth.getTransaction(hash)
{
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0x89b44e4d3c81ede05d0f5de8d1a68f754d73d997",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 50000000000,
  hash: "0x69b4a0768e72c3a679a1ae6fb490a831509c3c0a04674b646362d0a3d74689a4",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 10,
  to: "0xb7e13de69228c37cdff506ea474f31343af33c05",
  transactionIndex: null,
  value: 2000000
}
```

But the TXs are queued forever:

```
> txpool.status
{
  pending: 0,
  queued: 5
}
```

Also sending address is rich enough to pay off the gas:

```
> eth.getBalance("89b44e4d3c81ede05d0f5de8d1a68f754d73d997")
20000000000000000020
```

To compare, this is a valid transaction (created and sent by some client)

```
> eth.getTransactionFromBlock(11)
{
  blockHash: "0x41919469d7ed9232adbcacc820e61ad508b30eb5fc4750d3cebd748c22b110b8",
  blockNumber: 11,
  from: "0xb7e13de69228c37cdff506ea474f31343af33c05",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 50000000000,
  hash: "0xa4d4a22aa1fed291a7da00e24304f7093b4fc09b1c6a18692e4240d6d913d674",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 4,
  to: "0x89b44e4d3c81ede05d0f5de8d1a68f754d73d997",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: 20000000000000000000
}
```

Since geth can parse them, the format of my TXs has to be correct. I guess the only thing left is the signature. But I'm pretty sure the TX has been properly signed.

Is there a way to get more information about why a TX can't be processed? I'm using `geth` on my own blockchain so I can modify the source code if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I once encountered the same problem, and finally found that the key was `nonce`.

You may like to check if your nonce is continuous and based on the latest one of your address.

Hope it helps.

Comment: According to this [post](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2808/what-happens-when-a-transaction-nonce-is-too-high), your nonce can't be too high or lower than the latest transaction's one.